# My questions is related to jsp code in registration form

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

```
    This is JSP Code (process.jsp)

        <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
        <%@page import ="java.io.*" %>
        <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <title>JSP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <%!
        %>
        <% String FirstName=request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String LastName=request.getParameter("LastName");
        String Email=request.getParameter("Email");
        String Username=request.getParameter("Username");
        String Password=request.getParameter("Password");
        String RepeatPassword=request.getParameter("RepeatPassword");
        String MobileNumber=request.getParameter("MobileNumber");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ResultSet rs;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers(FirstName, LastName, Email, Username,Password,RepeatPassword,MobileNumber) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        st.setString(1,FirstName);
        st.setString(2,LastName);
        st.setString(3,Email);
        st.setString(4,Username);
        st.setString(5,Password);
        st.setString(6,RepeatPassword);
        st.setString(7,MobileNumber);
       34) int i=st.executeUpdate();
        if(i!=0)
        {
            //session.setAttribute("Username", Username);
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
            //out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
            }
            else 
            {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            }
        %>
        <h1>registration successful</h1>
        </body>
        </html>

        %>
```

I am using Eclipse IDE,Tomcat server, MySQL db. When I run reg.jsp on server it is running and asking registration details but while directing from reg.jsp to process.jsp the problem arises at (`int i=st.executeUpdate`). The server is throwing `An Exception Occured Processing JSP Page at line 34`

```
     int i=st.executeUpdate();
```

Firstly, I am registering at jsp registration page it is asking me registration details when I give my details it should take details and check for JDBC connectivity in process.jsp and store it in MySQL DB but it is showing me an error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/process.jsp] at line [34]

31: st.setString(5,Password);
32: st.setString(6,RepeatPassword);
33: st.setString(7,MobileNumber);
34: int i=st.executeUpdate();
35: if(i!=0)
36: {
37:     //session.setAttribute("Username", Username);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:588)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Password' cannot be null
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:669)
    org.apache.jsp.process_jsp._jspService(process_jsp.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Password' cannot be null
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
    org.apache.jsp.process_jsp._jspService(process_jsp.java:155)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

34: int i=st.executeUpdate();
```

The code is throwing me an error at line 34. Exception raised `An exception occurred processing JSP page [/process.jsp] at line [34]`. It has to check the user details and if all the details are greater than 1 it should throw me `registration successful, go to login`.

Comment: well, obviously the update is not executed. catch exception and add some logging to understand why update fails

Comment: Paste the stacktrace

Comment: borowis.you mean i have to check at reg.jsp(A registration page) the code actually looks correct

Comment: KDavid i pasted the stacktrace.please provide me solution

Comment: check password field from HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear through your stacktrace:

> Root Cause
>
> `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
>   Column 'Password' cannot be null`

You are trying to pass the value of column `Password` as `null` and hence the exception `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` thrown as well.

You would have defined your table with the column `Password` as `NOT NULL` and hence the error. Pass a meaningful value to your column `Password` and the issue should be resolved.

Recheck the `JSP` code if you are correctly passing the Password field or if the value is being passed correctly or not on the UI itself.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Error - Column 'Password' cannot be null

This simply means you are not getting value from your posted form correctly here.

String Password=request.getParameter("Password");

Please check -

1. Either you are not entering value in password field.
2. Check field name in reg.jsp, it should be like this -

**< input type="password" name="Password" >**

Please note your field name should be exactly same as you are trying to get from your request object here.

Comment: Great @KoushikReddy